# Getting from Lençóis to Morro de São Paulo

Tags: transit, buses, brazil

I'd like to travel quickly and cheap from Lençóis (in Chapada Diamantina) to Morro de São Paulo. I'm aware that there are night buses from Lençóis to Salvador, where I could take a ferry to Morro de São Paulo (information from Lonely Planet).

But I also read that it might be an option to take a lanchia from Valença to Morro de São Paulo, which might be 10 times cheaper. I read that I have to change buses in Feira de Santana, since there is no direct connection from Lençóis to Valença. But I didn't find any official information about that bus connection.

I am not Brazilian and therefore do not have a CPF, but I'd like to order the tickets in advance. If this is not possible, okay, I'm fine with that. But I need to have official information where to get the tickets in Brazil.

So, does anyone have information about that bus connection (Feira de Santana to Valença) or does anyone know a better way to get from Lençóis to Morro de São Paulo?

Comment: You're referring to Lencois in Chapada Diamantina?

Comment: If you have a Visa credit card, you can get bus tickets through http://www.plataforma10.com/. Also, quite a few of the bus connections have special booking processes, online, for foreigners who don't have a CPF.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited the names to clarify which cities I mean. There are so many cities with the same name :) sadly on plataforma10 I can't find Valença as a destination

Comment: Have fun in Lencois.  I was there a couple of years ago for a 3 day backpacking trip in Chapada Diamantina; it's beautiful!  Let me know if you are looking to hire a guide, and I will try and dig up the information for the guy we hired.  He was really excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I found a website where the bus connection is shown.](http://temonibus.com/passagem-onibus/feira-de-santana-ba-x-valenca-ba)

But obviously it isn't such a good route as the person stated it would be, so probably I will take a bus to Salvador and then a transfer via boat to Morro de Sao Paulo. Seems to be the fastest and cheapest alternative, though I didn't expect it to be...

Answer (score 3):

There's a ferry that takes one hour from Valenca to Morro which costs 20R$. From Salvador, you first have to take a ferry to Bom Despacho, which also takes about an hour, at 4R$ to 6R$, depending on the day, followed by a  bus from Bom Despacho to Valenca, taking about two hours, at about 20R$.

The direct catamaran from Salvador to Morro is said to take 2 hours (but apparently takes closer to 3) and costs about 80R$

I'm convinced you'd be able to get local transport to Valenca through Feira. Online information is... confusing, at best. temonibus only lists [connections that require a transfer](http://temonibus.com/passagem-onibus/feira-de-santana-ba-x-valenca-ba) (without the details), while Aguabranca [appears to go direct](https://www.aguiabranca.com.br) but referring to Valenca as 'Entrada de Valenca'. On Aguabranca, the trip takes about three hours and costs 25R$.

(Edit: I traveled from Salvador to Morro in March 2015.)